# Golang compilation error: undefined private function "findCluster" in exported function

Tags: go, import, package

I have the following code written in package `test/api` under project A:

```
func ListClusterTestCase() {
    ...
    getResponse, err = ocm.Connection.Get().
        Path(ClustersEndpoint).
        Parameter("order", "creation_timestamp desc").
        Send()
    getResult := ReadResponse(getResponse, err, 200)
    clusters := GetClusters(getResult)
    Expect(findCluster(clusters, clusterID)).To(BeTrue()) // <-- private function defined in a different file in test/api (called clusters_test.go)
}

...

func ProbeTests() []*ocm.TestCase {
    tc := []*ocm.TestCase{}
    ...
    tc = append(tc, ListClustersTestCase(cfg)...)
    return tc
}
```

And a file in a different **project** - project B - which imports this `test/api` package is trying to reference `ProbeTests`:

```
import (
    cms "my/project/test/api"
)


func AddTests(cfg *ocm.TestConfig) {
    ...
    ocm.AddTestCases(cms.ProbeTests(cfg))
}
```

I am getting the following compilation error when trying to compile project B:

```
../../go/pkg/mod/.../test/api/clusters_load_test_cases.go:59:12: undefined: findCluster
```

Why cant my project compile? why doesn't it compile the entire package `test/api`? does it only compile the file containing the exported `ListClusterTestCase`? when I compile project A it works just fine.

Comment: In what file is `findCluster` declared?

Comment: a seperate file in that package (called `clusters_test.go`)

Comment: Test files, those that end in `_test.go` are not included in the binary or package for non-test imports. Move it to a non-test file.

Comment: Gotcha thanks! can you please write it in an answer so that I could give you the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `findCluster` declaration to a non-test file if you don't want it to be omitted when the package is imported.

> When compiling packages, build ignores files that end in '_test.go'.

https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies